# equal symbol (=) behaves unacceptably in `doc`

Tags: makeindex, doc

I want to make a document with the package `doc`. When I type `=` in `\changes`, words before `=` disappear. Why would this happen?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{doc}
\begin{document}
\RecordChanges
\changes{v1}{0000/00/00}{test=hello}
    aaa
\PrintChanges
\end{document}
```

I compile the file `main.tex` with

```
pdflatex main
makeindex -s gglo.ist main.glo -o main.gls
pdflatex main
```

file related:

```
% main.glo
\glossaryentry{v1>!!=General:>test=hello|hdpindex{}}{1}

% main.gls
 \begin{theglossary} 

    \makeatletter\scan@allowedfalse

  \item v1\efill 
 \subitem General:\ hello\pfill \hdpindex{}{1}

 \end{theglossary}
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: well in index commands some chars have special meaning. Escape it `\changes{v1}{0000/00/00}{test!=hello}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You explicitly told makeindex to use `gglo.ist` style with the `-s` argument.

You can look at that file, which starts

```
actual '='
quote '!'
level '>'
```

so `=` is the `actual` character separating the index key text from the typeset form, you can quote it by prefixing with `quote` which this style sets to `!`

Comment: Thans very much! if I want to know more about someting like `actual` `quote`, what should I read?

Comment: @Syvshc /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/support/makeindex/ind.pdf  or the equivalent  For me `texdoc -l makeindex`  then select `2` works.